# CSS pseudo-class :nth child issues

Tags: css, google-maps, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a googlemap info-window.

I want to target this div
[image]

This seem to be the only way to target the div I want

```
.gm-style div div:nth-child(3) div:nth-child(4) div div div:nth-child(2) {
background: white !important; 
border-radius: 0px !important; 
box-shadow:0px 0px 60px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}
```

however when I do this it seems like i'm targeting not only my div but other div's as well.

[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not being specific enough with your selectors. `.gm-style div` applies to *any* `div` element contained within `.gm-style`, not just the direct children.

Based on the screenshot you've provided, you can select this element using:

```css
.gm-style > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div:nth-child(2)
```

Do note though that if any of those `div` elements which aren't a specific child have their own elements, this may also select them, so you may need to select their specific child indicies as well:

```css
.gm-style > div:first-child > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(4) > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:nth-child(2)
```

But without seeing the full code that may be a little overkill.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the full html you have"as it would be helpful to me", but any way you can try this

.gm-style > div > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(4) > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2)